# How to get the value(int) from a For Loop inside a Action Listener class to use in my main class?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have declared a global variable (`int number`) outside the main class:

```
public class BingoGUI {

    private static Random thing = new Random();
    public static int number = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
```

Then I need to use the variable `number` in an action listener class for a `Jbutton` I created:

```
    public static class theNextCall implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

            number = thing.nextInt(75) + 1;
            if (number < 16) {
                currentCall = "B" + number;
            } else if (15 < number && number < 31) {
                currentCall = "I" + number;
            } else if (30 < number && number < 46) {
                currentCall = "N" + number; 
            } else if (45 < number && number < 61) {
                currentCall = "G" + number;
            } else {
                currentCall = "O" + number;
            } 
            call.setText("the current call is: " + currentCall);
        }
    }
```

The Purpose is every time I click on the button (that has `theNextCall` action listener), if `number` equals `i` in my main class, `callButton[i]` will change background colour to yellow. But for some reason I can't access `number` from the Action Listener class, the `number` in my main class keeps getting the initial value I declared in the beginning which is 0.

Inside my main class:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){

        for (int i = 1; i < 76; i++) {
            callButton[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            callButton[i].setFont(new Font(Integer.toString(i), Font.BOLD, 9));
            callButton[i].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            callButton[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
            if (i == number){
                callButton[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        callBoard.add(callButton[i]);
        }
```

This is my entire code (unfinished bingo game gui) if you need the reference:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;

public class BingoGUI {

    private static int d = 0;
    //options panel
    private static String currentCall = "";              
    private static JLabel call = new JLabel("");
    private static JButton nextCall = new JButton("Next call");
    private static JButton bingo = new JButton ("Call Bingo!");
    private static Random thing = new Random();
    public static int number = 0;
    private static JButton[] callButton = new JButton[76];
    //playerCard
    private static int[] number2 = new int[76];
    private static JButton[] playerButton = new JButton[51];
    //cpuCard
    private static int number3 = 0;
    private static JButton[] cpuNum = new JButton[51];
    private static JPanel playerCard = new JPanel();
    //voice
    private static Voice v;
    private static VoiceManager vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();

    public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BINGO!");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel callBoard = new JPanel();
        JPanel cpuCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel options = new JPanel();
        JLabel test = new JLabel("");

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000,800);
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        //callBoard layout
        for (int i = 1; i < 76; i++) {
            callButton[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            callButton[i].setFont(new Font(Integer.toString(i), Font.BOLD, 9));
            callButton[i].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            callButton[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
            if (i == number){
                callButton[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        callBoard.add(callButton[i]);
        }
        //playerCard layout
        for (int a = 1; a < 51; a++) {
            if (a == 1 || a == 11 || a == 21 || a == 31 || a == 41 || a == 6 || a == 16 || a == 26 || a == 36 || a == 46){
            number2[a] = 1+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else if (a == 2 || a == 12 || a == 22 || a == 32 || a == 42 || a == 7 || a == 17 || a == 27 || a == 37 || a == 47) {
            number2[a] = 16+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else if (a == 3 || a == 13 || a == 23 || a == 33 || a == 43 || a == 8 || a == 18 || a == 28 || a == 38 || a == 48) {
            number2[a] = 31+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else if (a == 4 || a == 14 || a == 24 || a == 34 || a == 44 || a == 9 || a == 19 || a == 29 || a == 39 || a == 49) {
            number2[a] = 46+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else {
            number2[a] = 61+thing.nextInt(15);
            }
            playerButton[a] = new JButton(Integer.toString(number2[a]));
            playerButton[a].setFont(new Font(Integer.toString(a), Font.BOLD, 9)); 
            playerButton[a].addActionListener(new daub());
            playerButton[a].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            if (a == 23 || a == 28) {
            playerButton[a] = new JButton("");
            playerButton[a].setBackground(Color.RED);
        } 
            playerCard.add(playerButton[a]);
            if (a == 5 || a == 15 || a == 25 || a == 35 || a == 45){
                playerCard.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
            }
        }
        //loop for random number in cpuCard
        for (int b = 1; b < 51; b++) {
            if (b == 1 || b == 11 || b == 21 || b == 31 || b == 41 || b == 16 || b == 26 || b == 36 || b == 46){
            number3 = 1+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else if (b == 2 || b == 12 || b == 22 || b == 32 || b == 42 || b == 7 || b == 17 || b == 27 || b == 37 || b == 47) {
            number3 = 16+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else if (b == 3 || b == 13 || b == 23 || b == 33 || b == 43 || b == 8 || b == 18 || b == 28 || b == 38 || b == 48) {
            number3 = 31+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else if (b == 4 || b == 14 || b == 24 || b == 34 || b == 44 || b == 9 || b == 19 || b == 29 || b == 39 || b == 49) {
            number3 = 46+thing.nextInt(15);
            } else {
            number3 = 61+thing.nextInt(15);
            }
            cpuNum[b] = new JButton(Integer.toString(number3));
            cpuNum[b].setFont(new Font(Integer.toString(b), Font.BOLD, 9));
            cpuNum[b].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            if (b == 23 || b == 28) {
            cpuNum[b] = new JButton("");
            cpuNum[b].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            } 
            if (number3 == number){
                cpuNum[b].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
            cpuCard.add(cpuNum[b]);
            if (b == 5 || b == 15 || b == 25 || b == 35 || b == 45){
                cpuCard.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
            }
        }
        callBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,15));
        playerCard.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,10));
        cpuCard.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,10));
        callBoard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 250));
        playerCard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
        cpuCard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,250));
        options.add(test);
        options.add(call);
        nextCall.addActionListener(new theNextCall());
        options.add(nextCall);
        options.add(bingo);
        mainPanel.add(callBoard);
        mainPanel.add(cpuCard);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
        mainPanel.add(playerCard);
        mainPanel.add(options);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 600));
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static class theNextCall implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            v = vm.getVoice("kevin16");
            number = thing.nextInt(75) + 1;
            if (number < 16) {
                currentCall = "B" + number;
            } else if (15 < number && number < 31) {
                currentCall = "I" + number;
            } else if (30 < number && number < 46) {
                currentCall = "N" + number; 
            } else if (45 < number && number < 61) {
                currentCall = "G" + number;
            } else {
                currentCall = "O" + number;
            } 
            call.setText("the current call is: " + currentCall);
            v.allocate();
            v.speak(currentCall);
        }
    }
    private static class daub implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

            JButton daub = (JButton)e.getSource();
            daub.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer. [Answering you own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is highly encouraged!

Comment: @The Guy with The Hat I did... there is one answer down below with a checkmark, and I updated my code and even said, that's the fixed version.. look carefully please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (i == number){
    callButton[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

In your for-loop, there is this, which should set the color. However, if i equals the number, and, say i is 2, after setting the background to yellow, the loop continues and resets the background color. You might want to `break` if the condition is true.

Then, in the `ActionListener`: maybe you want a method there that checks the number and sets the background if the condition is *true*.

The code in the `main` (the for loop containing the above statement) is only run once when you start the program (I suppose that's the part where you want to check for `number` and set the color).

Comment: Alright I added this into my ActionListener class              `int y = Integer.parseInt(callButton.getText());
 if (number == y){
 callButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
 }`  and delete the same code in the main class, but it still won't work, error is `cannot find symbol callButton`

Comment: Your ActionListener encapsulates things. So `callButton` might not be visible inside. You might want to write another method that gets called from inside the listener, because inside the method (in the scope of the class), callButton will be visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stucked on this question for 2 days and you really helped me. now problem solved > <